# UART always repeats sent command (raspberry with SIM800)

Tags: uart, raspberry-pi4, sim800

I am trying to connect SIM800L module with Raspberry Pi 4 via UART using following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>         //Used for UART
#include <fcntl.h>          //Used for UART
#include <termios.h>        //Used for UART


using namespace std;

//-------------------------
//----- SETUP USART 0 -----
//-------------------------
//At bootup, pins 8 and 10 are already set to UART0_TXD, UART0_RXD (ie the alt0 function) respectively
int uart0_filestream = -1;

//************************************
//************************************
//********** UART TX STRING **********
//************************************
//************************************
void uart_tx_string (string tx_string)
{
    if (uart0_filestream != -1)
    {
        int count = write(uart0_filestream, (char*)tx_string.c_str(), tx_string.length());      //Filestream, bytes to write, number of bytes to write
        if (count < 0)
        {
            printf("UART TX error\n");
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "sent " << count << " bytes" << endl;
        }
    }
}

void read()
{
    //----- CHECK FOR ANY RX BYTES -----
    if (uart0_filestream != -1)
    {
        int t = 0;
        int rx_length = 0;
        do
        {
            // Read up to 255 characters from the port if they are there
            unsigned char rx_buffer[256];
            rx_length = read(uart0_filestream, (void*)rx_buffer, 255);      //Filestream, buffer to store in, number of bytes to read (max)
            if (rx_length < 0)
            {
                //An error occured (will occur if there are no bytes)
                printf("error\n");
            }
            else if (rx_length == 0)
            {
                //No data waiting
                printf("no data\n");
            }
            else
            {
                //Bytes received
                rx_buffer[rx_length] = '\0';
                printf("[%i] %i bytes read : %s\n", t, rx_length, rx_buffer);
            }
        }while(rx_length >= 255 && t++ < 10);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("steam closed\n");
    }
}

void setupUart()
{
    
    //OPEN THE UART
    //The flags (defined in fcntl.h):
    //  Access modes (use 1 of these):
    //      O_RDONLY - Open for reading only.
    //      O_RDWR - Open for reading and writing.
    //      O_WRONLY - Open for writing only.
    //
    //  O_NDELAY / O_NONBLOCK (same function) - Enables nonblocking mode. When set read requests on the file can return immediately with a failure status
    //                                          if there is no input immediately available (instead of blocking). Likewise, write requests can also return
    //                                          immediately with a failure status if the output can't be written immediately.
    //
    //  O_NOCTTY - When set and path identifies a terminal device, open() shall not cause the terminal device to become the controlling terminal for the process.
    
    uart0_filestream = open("/dev/serial0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);      //Open in non blocking read/write mode
    if (uart0_filestream == -1)
    {
        //ERROR - CAN'T OPEN SERIAL PORT
        printf("Error - Unable to open UART.  Ensure it is not in use by another application\n");
    }
    
    //CONFIGURE THE UART
    //The flags (defined in /usr/include/termios.h - see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/termios.h.html):
    //  Baud rate:- B1200, B2400, B4800, B9600, B19200, B38400, B57600, B115200, B230400, B460800, B500000, B576000, B921600, B1000000, B1152000, B1500000, B2000000, B2500000, B3000000, B3500000, B4000000
    //  CSIZE:- CS5, CS6, CS7, CS8
    //  CLOCAL - Ignore modem status lines
    //  CREAD - Enable receiver
    //  IGNPAR = Ignore characters with parity errors
    //  ICRNL - Map CR to NL on input (Use for ASCII comms where you want to auto correct end of line characters - don't use for bianry comms!)
    //  PARENB - Parity enable
    //  PARODD - Odd parity (else even)
    struct termios options;
    tcgetattr(uart0_filestream, &options);
    options.c_cflag = B9600 | CS8 | CREAD | CLOCAL;     //<Set baud rate     B9600 B115200 CLOCAL
    options.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
    options.c_oflag = 0;
    options.c_lflag = 0;
    tcflush(uart0_filestream, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(uart0_filestream, TCSANOW, &options);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "sending..." << endl;
    setupUart();
    
    uart_tx_string("AT\r\n");
    uart_tx_string("AT+CSQ\r\n");
    uart_tx_string("AT+CREG?\r\n");
    uart_tx_string("AT+ATE0\r\n");
    uart_tx_string("AT+ECHO?\r\n");
    uart_tx_string("AT+ECHO=?\r\n");
    uart_tx_string("AT\r\n");

    
    cout << "reading..." << endl;
    sleep(1);
    read();
    
    cout << "done" << endl;
    
    close(uart0_filestream);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The code should print some reasonable response from the module, however it always prints AT command that I am trying to send.

```
sending...
sent 4 bytes
sent 8 bytes
sent 10 bytes
sent 9 bytes
sent 10 bytes
sent 11 bytes
sent 4 bytes
reading...
[0] 56 bytes read : AT
AT+CSQ
AT+CREG?
AT+ATE0
AT+ECHO?
AT+ECHO=?
AT

done
```

Wiring is as follow:

- Raspberry Tx -> SIM Rx
- Raspberry Rx -> SIM TX

Wiring seems to be correct, when I unplug SIM module from a prototype board, nothing is received.

My /boot/cmdline.txt looks as follow:

```
root=/dev/mmcb root=PARTUUID=57509151-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
```

Comment: The code you copied (w/o acknowledgment) is low quality.  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)
and [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html)
 Your program uses non-blocking mode which it probably should not, since there's nothing in your code that needs it. Your program uses non-canonical mode, which it probably should not, since it is probably reading lines. Your program probably should be using blocking canonical mode to access the serial terminal.

Comment: ECHO is disabled for c_iflag (options.c_iflag = IGNPAR;) and c_oflag (options.c_oflag = 0;), AT+ATE0 command should disable echo on device side, but I still receive echo.

Comment: *"AT+ATE0 command should disable echo on device side,"* -- Incorrect, that's a bogus modem command.  Your program also hoses the modem with commands without waiting for a response/prompt between each command.  Your program sends incorrect command line termination character sequence.

Comment: Neither sending ```ATE0``` nor wating after each command don't change anything.